# How do I render a pug/jade template with React, Node and Webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, pug

I have a React/Node/Express application, and I am using Webpack to build it.

Currently, the structure of the directory is as such:

```
node_modules
public
    app
        main.js
        main.map.js
    index.html
src
    client
        components
            Home.js
            Header.js
            Root.js
            User.js
        main.js
    server
        views
            index.html
        index.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");

var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/client/main.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "main.js",
        publicPath: "/app"
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query:{
                    presets:["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "/src/server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && xcopy \"src/server/views/index.html\" \"public\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && xcopy \"src/server/views/index.html\" \"public/\" /F /Y"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

This works. My index.html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Basics</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/app/main.js"></script>
<!--Everything will be bundled in app/mainjs -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I do npm start, the application builds, and I can go to `localhost:8080` and see index.html, with the subcomponents loaded. The script loaded is 'app/main.js' which is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from "react-router";

//import newly created components
import {Root} from "./components/Root";
import {Home} from "./components/Home";
import {User} from "./components/User";

class App extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path={"/"} component={Root}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                    <Route path={"user/:id"} component={User}/>
                    <Route path={"home"} component={Home}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path={"home"} component={Home}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

What I want to do right now is instead of having the index.html, I want to have an index.pug with exactly the same content as index.html, and serve the pug template from the server file index.js. Can you tell me how I can do that? i tried a few things, but it messed things up too much, so reverted back to original situation.

Answer (score 0):

In the root directory:

```
$ npm install pug --save
```

server/index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

server/views/index.pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')

  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title React Basics
    //- Latest compiled and minified CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u' crossorigin='anonymous')

  body
    #app
    script(src='/app/main.js')
    //- Everything will be bundled in app/mainjs
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch your babel loader test, in webpack.config.js.

```
test: /\.js?/,
```

should be

```
test: /\.jsx?/,
```

The `?` in your regex means the preceding char was optional. In our case, we want babel to run on `*.js` and `*.jsx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pug-as-jsx : https://github.com/bluewings/pug-as-jsx-loader

You will find steps to do it here : can i use pug (ex-jade) with react framework?

A blog about this : https://medium.com/nishantsblog/pug-templates-for-react-presentation-components-7610967954a